# python Qlabel doesnt display images

Tags: python, pyqt

I am trying to change image dynamically in each 5 seconds, at first time it is displaying correctly, after that not showing anything, here is my code,

```
 def imageSelect(self):

    name = self.selectImageFromDb()#Fetch image name from database one by one

    self.pic.clear()
    myPixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8(path + "images/" + name))

    self.pic.setPixmap(myPixmap)

    self.pic.show()

    threading.Timer(3, self.imageSelect).start()`
```

Comment: Is self.selectImageFromDb() definitely returning different data every time?

Comment: Yes it is, that I have checked by printing the return value, thanks for replay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i take the line

```
threading.Timer(3, self.imageSelect).start()
```

out of the function `imageSelect()` i can reproduce this behaviour. I get the error message:

```
QObject::startTimer: Timers can only be used with threads started with QThread
```

so i used `QTimer` instead (successfully):

```
self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
self.timer.timeout.connect(self.imageSelect)
self.timer.start(1000)            # interval in milliseconds
```